# Debugging paused on exception: Segmentation fault C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, cs50

I'm writing a program for CS50 PSET 2 'Substitution.' When I run ./substitution in the command line, instead of printing the supposed "usage error", a segmentation fault is printed. In addition, when I try to use debug50, it gets paused on (see below), which once again says Segmentation fault, which doesn't allow me to use the debugger.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    string key = argv[1];
    int length = strlen(key); // LINE WHERE DEBUGGER GETS PAUSED ON
    // prints a usage error if a user inputs no key, or more than one key
    while (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./substituion key\n");
        return 1;
    }
    // prints an error if a user inputs a key that isn't 26 characters
    while (length != 26)
    {
        printf("Key must contain 26 characters.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int score = 0;
    // loops through key
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        // if the current character isn't a part of the alphabet, an error is printed
        if (key[i] < 'A' || key[i] > 'z')
        {
            printf("Key must contain only alphabetical letters\n");
            return 1;
        }
        // if the current character is lowercase, it is subtracted by 32 to make is uppercase, and that (ASCII) value is added to score
        if (islower(key[i]))
        {
            score += key[i] - 32;
        }
        // if the current character is uppercase, its ASCII value is added to score
        if (isupper(key[i]))
        {
            score += key[i];
        }
    }
    // if each uppercase letter of the alphabet's ASCII value are added together, it equals 2015;
    // if that added values of the key do not equal 2015, that means there is a repeated letter, which prints an error message
    while (score != 2015)
    {
        printf("Key must contain each letter exactly once\n");
        return 1;
    }

    string plainText = get_string("plaintext: ");
    printf("ciphertext: ");
    for (int j = 0; plainText[j] != '\0'; j++)
    {
        char plainLetter = plainText[j];
        //printf("plain: %c\n", plainLetter);
        if (isupper(plainLetter))
        {
            printf("%c", toupper(key[plainLetter - 'A']));
        }
        if (islower(plainLetter))
        {
            printf("%c", tolower(key[plainLetter - 'a']));
        }
        if (isdigit(plainLetter) || ispunct(plainLetter) || isspace(plainLetter))
        {
            printf("%c", plainLetter);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know what to do as I looked up what a segmentation fault is, but I couldn't correlate it to my problem. I'm thinking of rewriting my whole program without declaring a variable for the key's length, but I also want to know the cause of this 'segmentation fault.'

Comment: PSA: Check `argc` before **assuming** `argv[n]` exists.

Comment: if you're running with `./substitution`, you're not passing any arguments, so `argv[1]` doesn't exist.

Comment: those two first tests should not be 'while'

Comment: <O/T> rather than checking for a lowercase letter and subtracting a magic number from it, unconditionally call [toupper](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/toupper.3.html) on it

Comment: @pm100: In this case, `while` will work just as well as `if`, because the first loop iteration will never be completed. But you are correct that this is bad programming style.

Comment: I still consider string a confusing typedef

Comment: @ulix yes, the CS50 `string` typedef is a terrible thing, it makes students believe there is an _actual_ string type in C and then they wonder why their programs don't compile/behave "strangely"/crash.

Comment: @ulix: The reason for the `typedef` is so that students can work with strings before they learnt about pointers in week 4 of the course. Therefore, it would be more confusing for students to work with `char *`.

Answer (score 0):

Moving

```
string key = argv[1];
int length = strlen(key);
```

below

```
while (argc != 2)
{
    printf("Usage: ./substituion key\n");
    return 1;
}
```

seemed to fix it.

Comment: This answer can be improved by explaining why this fixes it. In case you do now know, I will explain in the next comment:

Comment: If you call `./substituation` without any command-line arguments, then `argc` will have the value `1` and `argv[1]` will have the value `NULL`. However, before you check `argc`, you effectively call `strlen(argv[1])`, which is equivalent to `strlen(NULL)`. Passing a `NULL` pointer to `strlen` is probably what is causing the program to crash. Therefore, you are crashing your program before you are checking the value of `argc`. However, If you perform the "move" mentioned in your answer, then you check `argc` and exit the program, before `strlen(NULL)` gets called.

Answer (score 0):

First you should to check the value of argc, if not equal to 2, then return program.

I think it's better to use `if(argc != 2)` rather then `while (argc != 2)` for Check the value of argc if weather equal to 2.

The same as `while (length != 26)`, use `if(length != 26)`.

and `while (score != 2015)` the same as, use `if(score != 2015)`

So here is my answer:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    //while (argc != 2)
    if(argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./substituion key\n");
        return 1;
    }


    string key = argv[1];
    int length = strlen(key); // LINE WHERE DEBUGGER GETS PAUSED ON
    // prints a usage error if a user inputs no key, or more than one key

    // prints an error if a user inputs a key that isn't 26 characters
    //while (length != 26)
    if(length != 26)
    {
        printf("Key must contain 26 characters.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int score = 0;
    // loops through key
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        // if the current character isn't a part of the alphabet, an error is printed
        if (key[i] < 'A' || key[i] > 'z')
        {
            printf("Key must contain only alphabetical letters\n");
            return 1;
        }
        // if the current character is lowercase, it is subtracted by 32 to make is uppercase, and that (ASCII) value is added to score
        if (islower(key[i]))
        {
            score += key[i] - 32;
        }
        // if the current character is uppercase, its ASCII value is added to score
        if (isupper(key[i]))
        {
            score += key[i];
        }
    }
    // if each uppercase letter of the alphabet's ASCII value are added together, it equals 2015;
    // if that added values of the key do not equal 2015, that means there is a repeated letter, which prints an error message
    //while (score != 2015)
    if(score != 2015)
    {
        printf("Key must contain each letter exactly once\n");
        return 1;
    }

    string plainText = get_string("plaintext: ");
    printf("ciphertext: ");
    for (int j = 0; plainText[j] != '\0'; j++)
    {
        char plainLetter = plainText[j];
        //printf("plain: %c\n", plainLetter);
        if (isupper(plainLetter))
        {
            printf("%c", toupper(key[plainLetter - 'A']));
        }
        if (islower(plainLetter))
        {
            printf("%c", tolower(key[plainLetter - 'a']));
        }
        if (isdigit(plainLetter) || ispunct(plainLetter) || isspace(plainLetter))
        {
            printf("%c", plainLetter);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Although this answer provides the solution to the problem of the program crashing, in my opinion, the answer is incomplete, because it does not explain why the crash occurred. As explained in my comment to the other answer, this is happening because OP's code is effectively calling `strlen(NULL)` before performing the check of `argc`. You may want to add this fact to your answer.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel if argc != 2, then exit program. When argc is equal to 2, how to let argv[1] = NULL？Do you have a example for explained?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. If the program is called with `./substitution` without any command-line arguments, then `argc` is `1` `argv[0]` will point to a string `"./substitution"` and `argv[1]` will have the value `NULL`. If the program is called with `./substitution key`, then `argc` will have the value `2`, `argv[0]` will have the same value as before, `argv[1]` will point to the string `"key"` and `argv[2]` will have the value `NULL`. Your posted code is correct.

Comment: OP is calling the program with `"./substitution"` (without any command-line arguments). Therefore, `argc` will have the value `1` and `argv[1]` will have the value `NULL`. For this reason, calling `strlen(argv[1])` is equivalent to calling `strlen(NULL)`, which is causing OP's program to crash. Your posted code does not have this problem, because you are checking `argc` before calling `strlen(argv[1])`.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel RIght. What I want to say is that when argc is not equal to 2, the program should exit directly. When argc is equal to 2, argv[1] cannot be equal to NULL.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.